# Error "(no value) used as value" from Go compiler using oklog/run

Tags: go, compiler-errors, go-context

I am working on a simple example of [oklog/run](https://github.com/oklog/run) package, and am seeing this compilation error in VS Code when trying to return a log of the error:

```
log.Errorf("abnormal termination: %s", err) (no value) used as value
```

In the description of group.Run it says

> "..Run only returns when all actors have exited. Run returns the error returned by the first exiting actor."

I’m wondering if that has something to do with it, like it can’t compile with the currently non-existent error because the run.Group hasn't all returned yet?

Thanks for any help you may have.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "time"

    "github.com/oklog/run"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func logAForever(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case err := <-ctx.Done():
            log.Error(err)
            return
        default:
            log.Info("A")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}

func logBFor10Sec(ctx context.Context) {
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        log.Info("B")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, testStopFunc := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    var group run.Group

    group.Add(func() error {
        log.Info("First actor added to run group. Starting execute function...")
        logAForever(ctx)
        return nil
    }, func(error) {
        log.Info("The first interrupt function was invoked.")
        testStopFunc()
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    })

    group.Add(func() error {
        log.Info("Second actor added to run group. Starting execute function...")
        logBFor10Sec(ctx)
        return nil
    }, func(error) {
        log.Info("The second interrupt function was invoked.")
        testStopFunc()
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    })

    if err := group.Run(); !errors.As(err, &run.SignalError{}) {
        // return
        return log.Errorf("abnormal termination: %s", err)
    }

}
```

Error from VSCode compiler:

[image]

Comment: Where is `myString` defined?

Comment: Apologies, that should read `err`. I get the same compilation error when passing `err` from line 57.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`log.Errorf` returns no value, but you are trying to return it via the `return` keyword.

Try this code instead:

```golang
if err := group.Run(); !errors.As(err, &run.SignalError{}) {
  log.Errorf("abnormal termination: %s", err)
  return
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!!